# Show that a function sequence converges in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

I am considering the function sequence $f_n(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{nx} + x^{1/3}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

The question is for which $p > 0$ this sequence converges in $L^p$.

At first I thought about applying Vitalis Theorem (in showing uniform integrability), however this sequence does not converge in measure, so it is not applicable. I tried for a while but cannot think of the right Ansatz to tackle this problem.

Can someone give me a hint on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!